# How to read from multiple lines in a file?

Tags: c++, fstream

I am learning C++ and am having a bit of a hard time with files. This is a little exercise that I am trying to do. The program is meant to read from a file and set it to its proper variables. The text file is as so:

Adara Starr          94
David Starr          91
Sophia Starr         94
Maria Starr          91
Danielle DeFino      94

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAXNAME = 20;

int main()
{
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("grades.txt");

    char name[MAXNAME + 1]; // holds student name 
    float average;          // holds student average

    inData.get(name, MAXNAME + 1);

    while (inData)
    {
        inData >> average;
        cout << name << "has an average of " << average << endl;

        //I'm supposed to write something here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run the code, only the first line is being read and displayed and then the program ends. More specifically, the output is

```
Adara Starr         has an average of 94
Adara Starr         has an average of 0
```

How do I read the next line from the txt file? I've also done `while (inData >> average)` in place of the inData condition but it also does the same thing minus the second "Adara Starr has an average of 0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const int MAXNAME = 20;

int main() {
    ifstream inData("input.txt");
    string str = "";

    while (!inData.eof()) {//use eof=END OF FILE
        //getline(inData, str); use to take the hole row

        /*can use string also
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        string avg;*/

        char firstName[MAXNAME];
        char lastName[MAXNAME];
        float avg;

        //you can read from a file like you read from console(cin)
        inData >> firstName >> lastName >> avg;//split the row

        cout << firstName << " " << lastName << " " << avg<<"\n";
        
    }

    inData.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
Adara Starr 94

David Starr 91

Sophia Starr 94

Maria Starr 91

Danielle DeFino 94

Comment: How do you make sure that the input will not cause a buffer overflow, e.g. if a name is MAXNAME characters long or more ?

Answer (score 1):

You read only one name, then loop to read averages. That doesn't match the contents of the file.

Use `getline` to read lines, then use a stringstream to parse the lines:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss{ R"(Adara Starr 94
David Starr 91
Sophia Starr 94
Maria Starr 91
Danielle DeFino 94)"};

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(ss,line)) {
        std::stringstream linestream{line};
        std::string first;
        std::string last;
        double avg;
        linestream >> first >> last >> avg;
        std::cout << first << " " << last << " " << avg << "\n";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it would help you a little bit, but I'd like to warn that since inner `for` loop checks only digits, you will loose your data if `average` will be consists of floating point numbers.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int MAXNAME = 20;

int main()
{
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("grades.txt");

    for(string line; getline(inData, line);) {
        // parse line
        // get number index
        size_t num_index = str.length() - 1;
        for(; num_index >= 0 && is_digit(str[num_index]); --num_index)
            ;

        string name = line.substr(0, num_index - 1); // skip space char

        if(name.length() > MAXNAME) 
            throw runtime_error("Name could not be more that " + MAXNAME + " length");

        float avarageStr = stof(line.substr(num_index + 1));

        cout << name << "has an average of " << average << endl;

        //I'm supposed to write something here
    }

    return 0;
}
```